# Add characters to the end of every element in a column of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame with column 1, titled "Label", containing dates in the format "MM/DD/YEAR 00:00". I want to add one more set of times (another ':00') to the end of every element of this column so that the full format is "MM/DD/YEAR 00:00:00". I'm pretty new to R, any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

If the `Label` column is character, then `paste` should work:

```
df$Label <- paste0(df$Label, ":00")
```

But note that most of R's date APIs (e.g. `strptime`, `as.Date`) can cope with a missing seconds component.  Depending on what you plan to do, you may not need to do this operation

Edit:

If you want to preserve both the dates and times, while obtaining a bona fide date type, then consider using `strptime`, which outputs a `posixlt`:

```
df$ts <- strptime("8/11/2017 8:55:00", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

or

```
df$ts <- strptime("8/11/2017 8:55 PM", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p")
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks. How can I modify this so that it is pasted at a specific point (e.g. 4 spaces from the end)?

Comment: @Nate Huh?  Why would you want that?  Can you show us what the final output for `Label` is?

Comment: I have two data sets in date formats and want to merge them together but can't till the Label column in each is formatted identically. One (df1) is in format "MM/DD/YEAR 00:00 AM/PM", the other (df2) is in "MM/DD/YEAR 00:00:00". as.Date doesn't work because the formats are "ambiguous".

Comment: Are the time components always zero everywhere?  Note that `as.Date` has no time component.

Comment: No, only the seconds are zero. df1 looks something like "8/11/2017 8:55 PM" and df2 looks something like "8/11/2017 8:55:00".

Comment: @Nate I gave you an option using `strptime`.  Use whichever option fits your data.